# Is there anything wrong with a static class which has totally unrelating, static, methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am currently working with a lot of C# code-behinds which were not originally written by me. They were written as massive lumps of horrible looking code and it is now my job to sort it out.

Anyway, there are a lot of repetitions of code, in lots of different aspx.cs files. For example, there are about five code-behind files which have exactly the same piece of code repeated a lot to output some text to a file. I could have the method:

```
private void outputToFile(string text)
```

repeated in the five different code behind files.

However, I am wondering if it is bad practice or just wrong to declare a static class called something like, "MethodHub" which holds outputToFile(string text) as well as a dozen or so other methods which do not relate to each other?

The overall goal is to access these methods from a static class so I can remove effectively hundreds of lines of code in others.

Can anybody see anything wrong with this, or any problems I may run into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to abstract such an utility behaviour by introducing interface

```
interface IOutputService
{
  void Output(string data);
}
```

and using your implementation implement class like

```
class FileOutputService : IOutputService
{
    // ...
}
```

on behalf of this interface, **the main point is to avoid static class** because

EDIT:

1. It would be mess to cover logic, which uses static clas calls, by unit tests
2. With static class it is much complex to switch a logic/behaviour easily, you have to change a logic implementation itself, for instance, you've to switch from a file output to a database output, it will be much easily to inject another service which implements common interface rather than play with potential refactoring

Comment: And why should he avoid the static class? Which benefits would he gain here from declaring an interface?

Comment: When he decided to cover whole logic by unit tests it would be mess to get rid of "hard coded" static class calls, anyway I preffer to inject such utilities as interface abstraction rather than static class.

Comment: I'm not saying that unit tests would be a bad idea, but be never talked about introducing unit tests. The fact that you prefer something does not mean that it's always the best or simplest solution.

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco, I must agree with you. BTW, I noted about tests, because initially he asked also about "or any problems I may run into"

Comment: Thanks for your input. Indeed unit testing isn't something I am concerned about regarding the context of the software I'm working with. I appreciate your input all the same and I will consider an approach along the lines of what you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Surely a static class holding several unrelated methods is not particularly elegant, but it's better than the "massive lumps of horrible looking code repeated everywhere" pattern.

When you do refactoring, always do it in small steps. Once you have removed the repetitions, it will be easier to improve further.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use static class, but avoid the thread-safety problem if there is any shared fields used by that method.

Comment: There's always `[ThreadStatic]`, so each thread gets its own instance.

Comment: Actually you wrong. After extract instance methods in static class there is some static fields can be needed, so you can loose thread-safety.